# Maybe Avraham didn't do the mitzvah of milah earlier because his mitzvah was to do it at 99 years old?

Tags: brit-milah, abraham

There is a famous question asked: Since Avraham Avinu observed all the mitzvos of his own accord, (kedushin 82a, Yevamos 28b) Why did he not circumcise himself before Hashem commanded him to at the age of 99?

There are many answers given. I will list some of those which I remember (I do not recall the sources):

1- גדול המצווה ועושה ממי שאינו מצווה ועושה  - Greater is one who is commanded and observes a mitzvah, than one who is not commanded and does it. Since Milah can only be done once, therefore Avraham waited until he was commanded.

2- Avraham was forbidden to circumsize himself because even a non-Jew is forbidden to do damage to his body. חובל בעצמו -  As long as he didn't have the mitzvah it would have been an aveira.

3- A "bris" is a covenant. As long as Hashem did not tell him of the bris there was no covenant.

4- R' Chaim brisker said that a bris can only be done on an ערל. Until the mitzvah of milah, Avraham was not considered an ערל.

5- The מהרש"א says that Avraham only began doing mitzvos after his bris milah.

There are other reasons, and some known difficulties with some of these reasons,  which I don't presently recall.

Question: Since Avraham knew what the Mitzvos would be, and what their details were, Maybe he also knew that (just as Yitzchok's mitzvah of milah was to do it at 8 days old, and Yishmael's mitzvah was to do it at 13 years old) he may have known that his own mitzvah of milah was only for him to do it at the age of 99 years old, and therefore no mitzvah of milah existed for him at all until the age of 99?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Are you asking why that's a weak answers?

Comment: bringing a source for avrahams knowledge that yishmaels bris was to take place when he is 13, would improve this question considerably. As now the question would be, if he knew that yishmael had to have it when he's 13, how come avraham didn't know that his own was to take place at 13

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm asking if there is any reason that my answer may be refuted, and since to me this seems more basic than (at least some) of the other answers, why didn't anyone use my reason?

Comment: @aBochur I didn't mean to imply that Avraham actually knew that Yishmael's bris was to take place when he is 13, or Yitzchak's at 8 days, just that we see that each had it's own time detail, so maybe Avraham knew of the time detail of his own mitzvah.

Comment: It can't be refuted AFAICT. It's just so ad hoc as to be completely uninteresting.

Comment: @DoubleAA Definition of ad hoc by Merriam Webster dictionary: 
1 a : concerned with a particular end or purpose 
b : formed or used for specific or immediate problems or needs
2 : fashioned from whatever is immediately available : improvised - Why is an explanation which is concerned with a particular end or purpose  and/or fashioned from whatever is immediately available : improvised uninteresting? I'm concerned with the question and tried to reach asolution which to me seemed basic and simple. Why do you have a problem with that?

Comment: @DanF Do you not understand MY question, or you don't understand the base question (which I listed the suggested answers to)?

Comment: I'm not sure what the various answers that you cite has to do with your question, honestly. I think your question really amounts to a translation of the Midrash mentioned in Kiddushin that the Avot performed all the mitzvot. Of course, there are many places where that principle may conflict, e.g. the mitzvot that can only be done in Israel, so, they couldn't have done **everything**. It seems that your question, here, is just why did Avraham wait until he was 99 to do *milah*? Now that you've listed several answers, it's unclear as to why you're rejecting them.

Comment: @DanF I'll explain: The base question, which I cited answers to was why did Avraham wait until he was 99 to do milah? I did not reject those answers, I suggested an answer of my own which seems more basic than any of the answers given. I meant to ask if my answer is a good answer, and if it is, why did the others not answer this more basic answer?

Comment: Maybe he was waiting all those years for his circulation and sensitivity to pain to diminish so he wouldn't be in total agony or possibly bleed to death?

Comment: @Gary I wasn't addressing answers to the base question, I suggested an answer of my own, which seems more basic than any of the answers given. I meant to ask if my answer is a good answer, and if it is, why did the others not answer this more basic answer?

Comment: IMO, and only IMO - a lot of the details concerning the Avot in the commentaries are imaginative, but usually logical conjecture of the commentators.  How could they REALLY know what the details of such a thing were around 1500 years+ before their days? Given the amount and diversity of non-Biblical writings and otherwise originating traditions, it seems like a fuzzy area, with plenty of room for backwards projection of then-current practices. Maybe your answer is the right one, maybe one of the others.  Without a time machine, there's no way to make absolutely sure. Again, IMO, and only IMO.

Comment: Why wouldn't Avraham have the mitzva of mila like any other mitzva? Also the pashtus by Yishmael, he happened to be 13 at that time when Avraham was commanded. Those that hold Avrahams mila was considered shelo bizmana then you don't have a question at all. Those that hold it was bizmano. That's just because that's when he was commanded. But pashtus he could've dont the mitzva before bigeder eino mitzuve viose.